# How to unbold the selected text in Edittext Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working with an edit text to support the properties of bold,italic and underline.I got succeed after selecting the text and make it bold. Now I want to remove the bold after clicking on Normal button.

**Typeface.NORMAL** is not working at here. Can any one suggest other option.

```
Button btnBold = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBold);
        btnBold.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSelection = etx.getSelectionStart();
                endSelection = etx.getSelectionEnd();


                Spannable s = etx.getText();
                s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection, 0);
            }
        });


Button btnNormal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNormal );
        btnNormal .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                **//What I have to do here.**
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check this post, you will figure the rest out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002177/how-to-bold-or-italic-or-underline-the-selected-text-in-edittext-programatically/42810064#42810064

Comment: I am facing the same issue that selected text is not updating, whole string updating

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Button btnNormal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNormal );
        btnNormal .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Spannable str = etx.getText();
               StyleSpan[] ss = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);

       for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
           if (ss[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD){
            str.removeSpan(ss[i]);          
           }
       }
    etx.setText(str);

    }
});
```

Comment: Any one has a clue, why just setting the type face to NORMAL is not working?

Answer (score 0):

in my project I use this construction

```
textView.typeface = Typeface.create(textView.typeface, Typeface.NORMAL)
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar to what you have used in first `onClick()` instead of `s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection, 0);` use `s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.NORMAL), startSelection, endSelection, 0);` in the second `onclick()`.

Comment: I have already mention in question that Typeface.NORMAL is not working.

Comment: Sorry for that, but i posted this answer before you edited your question.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use:

```
Typeface.NORMAL
```

You can check it on the Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#BOLD).