# How to bold or italic or underline the selected text in Edittext programatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, bold

I have to develop an App like sticky note. User enter the text in Edittext, while selecting the text I will open the popup to select the option like (BOLD,ITALIC,UNDERLINE). when user select the options i need to change the selected text..

Does anyone go through this?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714636/how-to-unbold-the-selected-text-in-edittext-android

Comment: i got the selected text from user. How to bold and show it in edittext?

Comment: may be you will get help from thishttps://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android  OR search `RichEdittext` in google

Comment: i ll check and get back to u

Comment: Thanks all... this link https://akashkubavat.wordpress.com/tag/edittext-bold/ and RichEdittext helped me...

Answer (score 2):

If you have found a way the popup the options and how to retrieve the selected option(Bold, Italics, Underline), Then use this to format the text

```
private void formatText(EditText editText) {
    int end = editText.length();

    //get the selected text position as integer
    start = editText.getSelectionStart();
    stop = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    //check if the user started the selection from the left or the right
    if (start > stop) {
        stop = editText.getSelectionStart();
        start = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    }

        //gets the texts as html incase if previous formatting exists
    String textBefore = Html.toHtml(new SpannableString(text.getText().subSequence(0, start)));
    String selectedText = Html.toHtml(new SpannableString(text.getText().subSequence(start, stop)));
    String textAfter = Html.toHtml(new SpannableString(text.getText().subSequence(stop, end)));
    //Check if the selected text is empty ie if the did not select anything
    if (!selectedText.equals("") || start != stop) {
       //format the text
       String formatted = "<b>" + selectedText + "</b>";
       //build back the text
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(textBefore);
        builder.append(Html.toHtml(formatted));
        builder.append(textAfter);

        editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
        //make the cursor stay after the selected text
        //you can also make the selected text selected here
        editText.setSelection(stop); 
        //clear your local variables
        textbefore = "";
        textafter = "";
        selectedText = "";
    }
    else {
        //you can also use snack bar here
        Toast.makeText(context, "select a text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I think this should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

Change `Typeface.BOLD`, `Typeface.ITALIC` or `UnderlineSpan()`

```
val spannableString: Spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(editText.text)
        spannableString.setSpan(
        StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
            editText.selectionStart,
            editText.selectionEnd,
            0
        )
editText.setText(spannableString)
```

Comment: It keeps formatting the whole string from the edit text